# Canvas item width related to the width of scrollregion

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In my orignal code I'm doing something like below, just with much more math.

It works but I dont like that I can see how the thumb of my scrollbar *(hscrbar)* is moveing from position 0 to 1 while I calculate the width in `get_width(self):` of my rectangel.
Cause in my original code I need to see it everytime I add something.

At the moment I havent an idea to solve this and you may are aware of a solution for it.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


class my_figure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.root = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # DownFrame
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='add', command=self.add)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.body = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
        self.hscrbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.body, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.vscrbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.body)
        self.Display = tk.Canvas(self.body,
                                 xscrollcommand=self.hscrbar.set,
                                 yscrollcommand=self.vscrbar.set)
        self.hscrbar.config(command=self.Display.xview)
        
        self.body.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nswe')
        self.vscrbar.grid(column=1,sticky='ns')
        self.hscrbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self.Display.grid(column=0, row=0,
                          sticky='nswe')
        self.vscrbar.config(command=self.Display.yview)
        self.hscrbar.config(command=self.Display.xview)

        self.x = tk.IntVar()
        self.y = tk.IntVar()
        self.x.set(10)
        self.y.set(10)
        self.height = 10
    def add(self):
        self.Display.create_rectangle(self.x.get(),self.y.get(),self.get_width(),self.height)
        self.old_x = self.x.get()
        self.old_y = self.y.get()
        self.x.set(self.old_x+40)
        self.y.set(self.old_y+20)
        self.Display.config(scrollregion=self.Display.bbox("all"))

    def get_width(self):
        if self.hscrbar.get()[0] == 0 and self.hscrbar.get()[1] == 1: #if scrollbar shows everything
            return self.Display.winfo_width()#return width of the canvas
        else:
            self.Display.xview_moveto(0) #scrollbar at postition 0
            self.root.update_idletasks() #update idletasks to get correct value
            value = self.Display.winfo_width()-round(self.Display.winfo_width()*self.hscrbar.get()[1])
            width = value+self.Display.winfo_width() #calculate the width
            self.Display.xview_moveto(1) #move to position 1 to show my the end of rectangel
            return width


figure = my_figure(root)
figure.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand what this means: _"I dont like that I can see how the scrollbar is moveing from 0 to 1"_. What does "moving from 0 to 1" mean? Can you describe that in a different way?

Comment: If you click on the add button, my code tells the scrollbar to move the slider at position 0, cause I need the percentage of hidden region. Then I want to show the user the end of the rectangel, so the slider of scrollbar (hscrbar) on the position 1(all the way right).

Comment: You need to click the button some often to see what happens. It is like flickering.

Comment: By "slider" are you referring to the thumb (the thing inside the scrollbar that you grab to scroll around)? It's also not clear if you want it to move when you add or if you _don't_ want it to move.

Comment: Yes :D Sorry, need to improve my english skills.

Comment: Updated my Question.

Comment: It's not clear what you want `get_width` to do. Is it supposed to return how wide the drawing is? I don't understand why you aren't just calling `bbox("all")` to get the extent of the existing drawing. Most likely, the cause of your problem is that you're calling `update_idletasks` since that causes the display to refresh.

Comment: Well, that is a good question. I'll try this and let you know if it fits to my problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley you are right. Seems like I was doing some overcomplicated for this. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is largely due to the fact that inside of `get_width` you're moving the scrollbar, calling `update_idletasks`, and then moving the scrollbar again. That call to `update_idletasks` causes the window to redraw. That redraw means you'll see the scrollbar move to the left, and then it will move back to the right when the function is finished.

It's not entirely clear what `get_width` is supposed to do, but I'm guessing you can remove all of that code and replace it with `self.Display.bbox("all")`, and then grabbing the x coordinates from the result to compute the width of the drawing.